# SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] exception while connecting to database using 000webhost

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to connect to my database using 000webhost but it give exception

> Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] ProxySQL Error: Access
>   denied for user 'id234191_faisalahmedansari20'@'2a02:4780:bad:f00d::4'
>   (using password: YES)

Below is my PHP file:

```
<?php

$host="localhost";
$username="id234191_faisalahmedansari20";
$password="*******";
$dbName="id234191_my_college_admin";

try {
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbName", $username, $password);
// set the PDO error mode to exception
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
echo "Connected successfully"; 
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

Is this is any privilege issue? If so then how can i set privilege in phpMyAdmin because 000webhost uses it i don't know how to create privilege.

Here is error screen while changing password:

[image]

And below is few error while trying to create new database and can't change privilege
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Seems like `privilege` issue as you mentioned

Have assigned that user to that particular DB ?

if you still face the problem check here.

Open `phpmyadmin` -> select database -> `privileges` top of menu -> where you can see all the list of users and edit their privileges also.

Comment: So even you cannot go inside the db `id234191_my_college_admin`?

Comment: Seems like you have not assigned user to access that db , refer here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yYmVDNbFkEY