# Access denied for user 'root' Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I try to run my project online (move from local to host) but i get this error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] ProxySQL Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'2a02:4780:bad:f00d::8' (using password: NO) (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `posts`)
```

this is my `.env` file:

```
APP_NAME=TJD
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:7tnIYoBvOfhfNXGSucngHdi2EMSMau3f9YTnQsrqgRE=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=https://tjd.000webhostapp.com/

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=ixxxxx23_xxxxxx
DB_USERNAME=idxxxxxx_xxd
DB_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=


TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN=

TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY=
TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET=
TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN=
TWITTER_ACCESS_SECRET=

FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID=
FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET=
CALLBACK_URL_FACEBOOK=
```

What is the issue? why do i get this error?

....................................................................

Comment: Is this your host `.env` file ?

Comment: yes the env right now in my host

Comment: my DB_HOST name is localhost as well, just like localhost in my pc.

Comment: Have you tried changing `DB_HOST=localhost` to `DB=127.0.0.1` ? Are you using the correct DB username and password?

Comment: Are you sure you are using the "mysql" connection? Because that error clearly states you are trying to access the database with user root and without password. What about your db config file, can we see it? Actually the .env file SHOULD NOT BE commited from local to server.

Comment: This might be a 000webhostapp.com problem. Posible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41010706/sqlstatehy000-1045-exception-while-connecting-to-database-using-000webhost

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same error and it took me longer to solve it than i would have wanted, so i'm posting the solution i got to save someone's time. Im hosting my laravel 5.3 site on free webhosting at 000webhost.com. This error shows up i think when your login credentials are wrong. Here is my MYSQL connection details in my .env file.

```
`DB_CONNECTION=mysql
 DB_HOST=localhost
 DB_PORT=3306
 DB_DATABASE=id1767899_keen
 DB_USERNAME=id1767899_root
 DB_PASSWORD=rootadmin`
```

Previously i did not have the `id1767899_` prefix on the database name and username. You get this prefix on the manage database link, where there is a button to manage your database. After adding this prefix you will get a new error like `Wrong COM_STMT_PREPARE response size. Received 7` . To solve this error go to config/database.php file and add the following option.

`'options' => [PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true],`

Save the file and login again. This worked for me.I found the solution [at the forums here](https://www.000webhost.com/forum/t/wrong-com-stmt-prepare-response-size-received-7/66868/7)